# aws glue how to override files in s3 with same file name in scala

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, scala, etl, aws-glue

hey i have  a data frame with

```
df.withColumn("file_name", input_file_name)
```

i have file name with some other columns

i need to override the same file in s3

i used something like

```
            df.toDF()
              .write
              .mode("overwrite")
              .format("json")
              .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour")
              .save(WRITE_URI)
```

but i am not able to see the data getting  override  or updated

i get execution error like

```
Exception in User Class: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Can not create a Path from an empty string
```

printed my dataFrame  there is no empty value

please help me to resolve this

Comment: What is the value for the WRITE_URI ? Also what is the file that you are reading - is it a single file? Because when you are writing the dataframe you are partitioning By Year, month,day and hour so the new files would be created accordingly inside these directories for the path you provide.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya s3//location